# How to know SMS number and phone number is the same?

Tags: android, sms

I'm working on a project that is similar to Message in android.
There are 2 types of number : sms number and phone number.
For example : I always receive sms with number is: +84973612399. But her phone number is 0973612399. How can I know that 2 numbers only belongs to a person?

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to edit out that phone number and put a dummy in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [PhoneNumberUtils.compare](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html#compare%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to compare both numbers.

Example

```
//Compare phone numbers a and b, return true if they're identical enough for caller ID purposes.
if (PhoneNumberUtils.compare("+84973612399", "0973612399")) {
   Log.d(TAG, "Both are identicaly same"); 
} else {
   Log.d(TAG, "Doesn't match");
}
```

Result is

> Both are identicaly same

Comment: You actually save my life. Thanks youuuuuu ^^

Comment: I'm feeling excited now because I wasted lots of time for dealing with this problems. Thanks again ^^